# Vb.net Difference between assigning properties directly and using invoke method

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Both of the lines below mentioned are working. it is used enabling or disabling a button inside a form. but question is why should we use form.Invoke method over direct method of assigning.

Method 1:

```
frmPrint.Invoke(Sub() frmPrint.btnCancel.Enabled = False)
```

Method 2:

```
frmPrint.btnCancel.Enabled = False
```

Thanks,
Sarathi

Comment: You `[Control].Invoke(delegate)` when the property/method is set/called from a thread other than the UI thread. You should use `.BeginInvoke()` instead of `Invoke()`.

Comment: In general I cannot tell you **why you should use** Invoke(...) instead of assigning a value directly to a control property. But I can tell you, **when it makes sense** to do this: As Jimi already has mentioned about, all UI elements are exlusively driven by the UI thread, if I may call it that way so far. If you now want to call _frm.btnCancel.Enabled = False_ from another thread this will fail, except you did it with Invoke(...). So you should use that way, if your code is (potentially) not running in UI thread. There are even other techniques to make sure, code is executed by UI thread.

Comment: thanks @jimi and user1470240 , now i got some idea on this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Invoke()` method Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the controls underlying window handle.

In simple words the `Invoke()` method should be used when updating the GUI from other thread that is not the GUI main thread.

Hence, if you are updating the GUI from the main thread you dont have to use the `Invoke()` method.

**Safe Multi-Threading GUI Updates**

When updating GUI from other thread you can not do this because `Cross-thread  exception` will be thrown:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf changeGUI)
    t.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub changeGUI()
    Button2.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

But when using `Invoke()` the GUI will be updated safely with the help of the delegate, so you should do it like that:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf changeGUIThreadSafe)
    t.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub changeGUIThreadSafe()
    Me.Invoke(Sub() Button2.Enabled = False)
End Sub
```

Comment: excuse the delay in marking as answer. thanks jona.